# Parametric differentiation equation problem

Tags: calculus

If $y(t)=t^m+t^{-m}$ and $x(t)=t+t^{-1}$, show that:
$$
(x^2-4)\frac{d^2y(x)}{dx^2}+x\frac{dy(x)}{dx}-m^2y(x)=0
$$
How do I go about showing this? I tried plugging all the values in but it gets too complicated. I know that $x^2(t)=(t-t^{-1})^2+4$ and $y^2(t)=(t^m-t^{-m})^2+4$.

Any tips?

Comment: use that $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$

Comment: I've gotten that far, and have the second derivative as well, but do I just plug everything in? Or is there a way to simplify after having plugged in the values?

Comment: It may help to put $t=exp(is)$

Comment: In the mean time I worked it out using this substitution and the equation is confirmed. The trick is that $x=2cos(s)$ and $y=2cos(ms)$.